# How can i use in memory database to my Ionic app

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework, in-memory-database

I am new to ionic app development and also In Memory database, how can i use in memory database to my ionic app. For My Ionic app am using AngularJS, HTML5 and CSS. I need Data transaction from My Ionic app to Inn memory Database. Please give me some useful links. Thanks In advance.

Comment: what actually is 'Memory database'..?do u want to [store locally](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/) or use [sqlite or pouchdb](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/) to store..?

Comment: Yes, I want to store Locally, is there any better solutions help me

Comment: What Data do u want to store..!like..! Is it big list..?if so, then u shud use any one of  dB..!

Comment: Simple data, like list of user details. Any One means ?

Answer (score 1):

try [this](https://github.com/auth0/angular-storage) way..!

command to install local storage

```
bower install a0-angular-storage
```

in index.html

```
<script src="lib/angular-storage.min.js"></script>
```

make service :

```
angular.module('app', ['angular-storage'])
.factory('UserDetailsService', function ( store ,$rootScope) {
    var self = {};
    self.getUsers = function () {
        var users = store.get('_userList');
        if (users){
            return users;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    };
    self.setUsers = function(UserList) {
        $rootScope.users = UserList;
        store.set('_userList', UserList);
    };
    return self;
});
```

in controller:

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope,  UserDetailsService,store) {
    //to store data..!
    $scope.doLogin = function () {
        $http.post('**** URL *****', $scope.loginData).
            success(function (response) {
                $scope.users = response.result;
                UserDetailsService.setUsers($scope.users);// call to service..!
            }).error(function (response) {
            });
    };
    //to get local store list
    $scope.users = UserDetailsService.getUser();
    //to remove local store data
    $scope.toRemoveLocalData = function () {
        store.remove('_userList');
    };
})
```

one more [simple way](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/06/saving-data-with-ionicframework/)..

Answer (score 1):

you can use **local storage**, First make a **angular factory**, then use this **angular factory** in your **ionic app controller**, sample code is given below:

**Angular Factory** ::

```
 .factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
     return {
        set: function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },
        get: function(key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        },
        setObject: function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        },
        getObject: function(key) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
       }
   }
}]);
```

**Angular Controller** :

```
 .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $localstorage) {
       // set data to $localstorage
       // you can use this json data anywhere in your app
       $localstorage.setObject('object_name', json_data);



      // get $localstorage data
      var json_data = $localstorage.getObject('object_name'); 
 });
```

**NB::** localstorage is only for limited data. For large number of data, you better **sqlite**